# Why would you store an artifact with a custom POM

Tags: java, apache, maven

I'm reading the about the [Apache Maven Install Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/custom-pom-installation.html).

Why would you store an artifact with a custom POM? What are the advantages?

> Installing an artifact with a custom POM The Apache Maven Install
>   Plugin can include a pre-built custom POM with the artifact in the
>   local repository. Just set the value of the pomFile parameter to the
>   path of the custom POM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, you might want to install a library locally with the `maven-install-plugin` without having Maven downloading it from repositories. In such a case, and when this library also has a POM, you can also intall it by specifying the [`pomFile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#pomFile) attribute.

The advantage is that when having a dependency on that library, Maven will be able to resolve the transitive dependencies to add to your build because you installed the real POM of that library. That's the main feature of that parameter: specify the real POM of a library that, for some reason, you can't download from reporitories.

If you don't specify a POM (and the artifact does not contain one), the `maven-install-plugin` will generate a POM or not depending on the [`generatePom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#generatePom) attribute value. The problem is that when there is no POM, or the POM was generated, Maven won't be able to resolve the transitive dependencies and you will have to re-add each one of them, which defeats the whole purpose of Maven.